# Why can't GHC derive instances for Monoid?

Tags: haskell, ghc, monoids

GHC has a few language flags, such as `DeriveFunctor`, `DeriveDataTypeable` etc., which enable compiler generation of derived instances for type classes other than those allowed in Haskell 98. This especially makes sense for something like `Functor`, where the laws of that class dictate an obvious, "natural" derived instance.

So why not for `Monoid`? It seems like for any data type with a single data constructor:

```
data T = MkT a b c ...
```

one could mechanically produce a `Monoid` instance (excuse the pseudocode):

```
instance (Monoid a, Monoid b, Monoid c, ...) => Monoid T where
  mempty =
    MkT mempty mempty mempty ...
  mappend (MkT a1 b1 c1 ...) (MkT a2 b2 c2 ...) =
    MkT (mappend a1 a2) (mappend b1 b2) (mappend c1 c2) ...
```

I'm aware that the [derive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/derive-2.5.8) package [provides this](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/derive/latest/doc/html/Data-Derive-Monoid.html), but my question specifically is whether there's a reason why GHC does not.

Comment: There's usually only sensible way to make a `Functor` instance.  The same is not true about `Monoid`.

Comment: @augustss can you elaborate a bit? this is probably the sort of answer i'm looking for.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's really an arbitrary decision to not be able to derive `Monoid`, but monoids are also very general so there is typically many ways to make a type a monoid.  Here's an example:

```
data T = A | B | C deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum)

type Mon a = (a, a -> a -> a)

m1, m2, m3, m4 :: Mon T
m1 = (A, max)
m2 = (C, min)
m3 = (A, \ x y -> toEnum $ (fromEnum x + fromEnum y) `rem` 3)
m4 = (B, f4)
f4 A _ = A
f4 B x = x
f4 C _ = C
```

This shows four reasonable ways to make `T` a monoid (with `Mon` containing the unit and the binary operation).  The first is the monoid from taking the maximum, the second the monoid from taking the minimum, the third the monoid from modulo 3 arithmetic, and the fourth is the monoid used for the `Ordering` type.  Nothing really stands out as the natural way.

Answer (score 8):

You could ask the same for `Num` and some other classes. It would be inconsequential: All other standard derivations work for data types with multiple constructors.

As a replacement, you can use newtype deriving `newtype T = MkT (a,b,c) deriving Monoid`.

Similar extension: you can make the empty datatype an instance of almost every type class.

The `deriving` clause was always ad-hoc and inconvenient part of the Haskell, because it worked only for predefined classes. Adding even more ad-hoc extensions would complicate language. Instead, GHC has recently got support for [generic deriving](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC.Generics).

Comment: Well, as ad-hoc as `deriving` may be, they've continued to expand its power. Again, I know there are alternative mechanisms for deriving `Monoid`; instead I'm asking specifically why `DeriveFunctor` (and others) exists, while `DeriveMonoid` (and others) does not. Is it just arbitrary?

Comment: In the end it's arbitrary, but the proposed extension seems to be much less useful. A special language feature to serve most functors seems good to me. A special language feature to serve product monoids seems to little to warrant addition. You would need to think about scope (if `Monoid` then what other classes?). Note that useful monoids often use newtype wrappers anyway. So you write `data T = T (Sum Integer) (Endo Char)` to use that form of deriving, which is bit ugly to use (need to match on nested constructors).

Comment: There are plenty of useful monoids that are sum types, but this implementation can't derive any of their instances.  =(

Comment: @mergeconflict there is only one sensible definition of Functor for a given type. Any other valid instance is equivalent. With Foldable and Traversable, there is a slightly less satisfying story about how there is an implied best practice in the ordering of fields. All of these work over multiple constructors and don't have a huge pile of alternate definitions like Monoid. If you want a tuple of monoids, just use (,,,,).