# Automatic propagation of monoidal mappend

Tags: haskell, monoids

Let's say I have a monoid defined as this:

```
data TotalLine = TotalLine { totalQuantity :: Int, orderTotal :: Float }

instance Monoid TotalLine where
  mempty = zero
  mappend = add
```

As **totalQuantity** and **orderTotal** are both numbers they also form a monoid under **(+)**
Is there any way to define

```
add :: TotalLine -> TotalLine -> TotalLine
```

so, Can I just propagate the **mappend** call on each field instead of having to manually define something like

```
add line1 line2 =
  TotalLine {
    totalQuantity = totalQuantity line1 + totalQuantity line2,
    orderTotal = orderTotal line1 + orderTotal line2
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's `generic-deriving` package matches exactly your requirement:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import           Generics.Deriving.Monoid
import           GHC.Generics

data T = T {str :: String, str' :: String}
  deriving (Generic, Show)

main = undefined

instance Monoid T where
  mempty = memptydefault
  mappend = mappenddefault
```

And some result from ghci:

```
> T "a" "b" `mappend` T "c" "d"
< T {str = "ac", str' = "bd"}
```

But it doesn't work out-of-box for your `TotalLine` data type, since both `Int` and `Float` do not have an instance of `Monoid`.

Also add a dependency just for that purpose is not so economic. You'd better implement the `Monoid` instance manually.

---

There has been [some discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165316/why-cant-ghc-derive-instances-for-monoid) on why GHC cannot derive Monoid instances, it turned out in general such derived instance may not be unique. <s>But in the special case when the data type have only one constructor with concrete and monoidal fields the derived instance is unique.</s>

Comment: "but in the special case when the data type have only one constructor with concrete and monoidal fields the derived instance is unique." Although there is a *natural* monoid, it still isn't unique. It could `mappend` some of the fields in reverse order.

Answer (score 7):

Note there are several monoids with domain Int (Nat, Float, ..)
so I would find it highly confusing to read code that has `instance Monoid Int`. Then `mappend` could be any of plus, times, max, min, and a lot more.

Comment: Minor note: I was confused at first by the parenthesis, since I misread it to imply that Nat,Float,... are distinct monoids with domain Int, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

If you're fine changing the type a little (but that is still isomorphic to yours), you could try this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
import Data.Monoid

newtype TotalLine = TotalLine (Sum Int, Sum Float) deriving Monoid
```